# Gulp with browserify: Cannot find start module

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have pretty much the exact same problem as described in [Gulp with browserify: Cannot find module src/js/main.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277666/gulp-with-browserify-cannot-find-module-src-js-main-js): I have a JavaScript project that I can build using browserify from the command line, but not in gulp. But the solution for that question does not work for me.

From the command line:

```
browserify -t reactify ./js/inspector > static/js/inspector.js
```

works perfectly. When I run the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  return browserify({
        transform: ['reactify'],
        entries: ['./js/inspector.js']
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('inspector.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js/'));
});
```

and run it, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../inspector'
```

and also the generated file has the same length as the CLI file but not the same order of modules. Which puzzles me.

I have the same version of browserify in my global and local modules, and I've not knowingly configured it, anywhere.

Unlike Ben Davis, who asked the other question, adding a ./ to the start of my path changes nothing.

I don't understand why browserify gives a different, and broken, output, when run through gulp.

Update: The directory structure of the project:

```
gulpfile.js
node_modules/
js/                  (also contains subdirectories with JS code)
    inspector.js
static/
    js/
        inspector.js (built)
```

Update: When I run Browserify through Grunt, I also get a different file, but it works.

Comment: can you give us an idea of your folder structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulp with browserify: Cannot find module src/js/main.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277666/gulp-with-browserify-cannot-find-module-src-js-main-js)

Comment: @SomeKittens It is not, I specifically link to that issue at the very start, and explain why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Well, let me clarify that: it is more or less the same issue, but the solution does not work in my case.

Comment: I would try deleting gulp from both locations and reinstalling; Also, can you change the output file name to be different from source?  Are you loading all dependencies (e.g. gulp = require('gulp'),
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  bundle = require('bundle'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream'))

Comment: I tried deleting and reinstalling, no change.
I was able to change the output filename without any problems.
I loaded all the dependencies except bundle - I had never seen anyone install and require that. But I tried that, no change.

I've solved the issue though, I just need to figure out how to answer my own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had other modules that required the root module, à la:

`var inspector = require('../../inspector');`

This is what caused the problem (somehow). Putting in a root module that was never required by anything else made gulp + browserify work without any problems.

I'll see if I can create a minimal reproduction project for the gulp / browserify maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your return function in an IIFC.

```
//======================================
// Task: browserify
//======================================
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  return (function() {
    browserify(config.src)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source(config.name))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
  })();
});
```

I am using the above successfully in a current proj.

Comment: I've tried this, same effect: a different file with the same size is generated, and I get the same error message in the browser.